# Several connections remain open with websocket client inspite of websocket close

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, java-websocket

I am using socket.io-client 0.6.3 https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java for making websocket client. I have written a connect method as below:-

```
public void connect(String host, int port) throws Exception {
        socket = IO.socket(String.format(url, host, port));
        //socket connect, disconnect, error event
        subscribeEvents(socket);
        socket.connect();
    }
```

where subscribeEvents method is as below

```
void subscribeEvents(final Socket socket) {
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                socket.emit(CommandType.JOINCOMMAND.getValue(), CLIENT_NAME);

            }

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                errorDisconnectListener.onDisconnect();
            }

        }).on(InitialCommandValue.GETAVAILABLEPERSPSETIVESVALUE.getValue(), new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                socket.emit(CommandType.RESPONSECOMMAND.getValue(), commandMessageListener.getPerspectives(args));
            }

        })
.on(Socket.EVENT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                errorDisconnectListener.onError();
            }

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_MESSAGE, new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                commandMessageListener.onMessage(args);
            }

        });
    }
```

Now when I get the event disconnect or error due to network problem or the machine becomes unreachable, I shutdown the socket as below

```
 this.socket.off();
        this.socket.disconnect();
        this.socket.close();
        this.socket = null;
```

and calls the connect method again until the connect event gives the confirmation.

But the problem is that once the network comes in, all the socket connection comes back online and start giving the socket events(means I get the various duplicate events).

My requirement is that once the network goes away, dispose the socket and try connecting again and again until the connection succeeds(keepalive mechanism).

Can anyone helps me where I can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix it with by making websocket connection with below options.

```
IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
    opts.forceNew = true;
    opts.reconnection = false;
    socket = IO.socket(String.format(url, host, port), opts);
```

The above options will make websocket connection dispose once the websocket gets close and will allow the new websocket connection to gets created.

This way I am able to receive the single event and makes my keepalive mechanism for websocket feasible.